# Ng4LoadingSpinner timeout after 5 sec

Tags: angular, angular5, spinner, loader

I am facing one problem while using Ng4LoadingSpinner.
it is disappearing automatically after default timeout 5 seconds,
but our request is still in progress. if we increase the timeout then it works fine.
If there is another solution to cancel the default timeout rather than increasing the timeout, please suggest the solution.

```
<ng4-loading-spinner [threshold]="0" [timeout]="60000" [zIndex]="100000"> </ng4-loading-spinner>
```

Comment: can you post the method where you are using it...

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng4-loading-spinner-zgzu2m) is a stackblitz for those who want to experiment with that component.

Comment: you can use *ngIf

Comment: @Suryan I am not using it for any specific method. I used it to show loader all over system for each `HttpClient` request. When service returns response loader stops.

Comment: Can I cancel its timeout property so that it loader will stop only after when we close it programatically and no timeout period will get used, rather than increasing the value of default timeout to 1 min or higher.

Comment: Working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng4-loading-spinner-63eq98?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Suryan I unable to find the way to tackle default timeout there.

Comment: make demo of your issue if possible

Comment: sorry I cannot make the live demo for same, but i think increasing default timeout and close loader when response count becomes 0 works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to fix is keep a high default timeout and manually show and hide your spinner

Add below line to your component constructor in which you want to use the loader:

```
private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService
```

When on submit or any function call show and spinner and after request is completed hide it:

```
    submit(){

    //show spinner
     this.spinnerService.show();

       //service call or any process
       this.serviceCall.get().subscribe((result)=>{
        if(result.success)
         {
           //hide spinner
           this.spinnerService.hide();
         }

        }

    }
```

**Hope this will help.**